# Model Spinup time

Tags: stability, model

While I look up programming and technical stuff on Stack Overflow all the time, I figured that would probably be the wrong forum for a question like this.

Some background: I'm a climate modeler working on paleoclimates and data comparison for warm climate modes, and I've been writing ice sheet models in C and C++ for a while. It's been painful but finally I'm happy enough with how the ice is behaving to incorporate it into the GCM we've been using. The question boils down to the following: Assuming you have a fairly decent simulation of the present day state, how long would you expect a simulation to need to run to adjust to a similar warm climate state, in my case the Eemian. I've run it through 2000 years, but my ocean salt is still climbing (very very slowly, but linearly -- 0.05% per century, more or less) Physically that translates to a little more than one full ocean overturning.

Comment: Seems to me that most of the time, this is just figured out by trial and error - try it and see when all relevant variables start to stabilise. Unless you know of the spin-up time of similar models, in which case you can probably just use those.

Answer (score 3):

Each of your subsystems -- and likely also each coupling between subsystems -- will have an intrinsic time scale. What that is of course depends on your system. The spin up time will then be a small multiple of the maximum of all of the time scales that are relevant in the transition you are considering.